# Get Request Parameters Passed To Ajax When Chaining Ajax Calls Using Promises and Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am using JQuery to chain ajax calls in a WordPress environment to hit a third-party API.

The workflow is such that I first get an array of objects each with a `start_date` and `end_date`. I then need to make ajax calls using those parameters and associate the response with the original params. I also need to do the ajax requests one by one because it isn't critical they all load right away and I want to control the network requests (there are a lot of other assets loading on the page).

Anyway, here is my code:

```
var superobjects; //variable to hold final result - want the response and the original date params in this array of objects
var callback = function(result) {
  superobjects.push(result); //callback of ajax request using jQuery.when
};
var requests = []; // array to hold requests before doing them one at a time with jQuery.when

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  requests.push(jQuery.ajax({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'superplugin/v1/superdooperendpoint/' + api_key + "/" + data[i].start_date + "/" + data[i].end_date,
    method: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      // Set nonce here
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce);
    },
    done: function(data) {
      console.log({
        start_date: data[i].start_date,
        end_date: data[i].end_date
      });
      //this console.log above never fires
    }
  }));
}
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(superobjects) //no request information here!
}, 2222);

jQuery.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(function(result) {
  callback(result) //run the ajax sequentially and then do the callback - problem is I've lost the request params here!
});
```

As you may be able to tell, when I do the `superobjects` in the log, it doesn't have any information from the `start_date` or `end_date` I used to create the request, just the result of the ajax call. Is there anyway to still have this sequential ajax workflow and still get the request params in my final `superobject`? I'm guessing there is with clever use of functions and scopes, but I don't see it right now so am looking for help! :)

Comment: If the log in `done` never shows it sounds like requests are failing. Add error handler and find out why. Can also inspect actual requests in browser dev tools network. Once you sort that out will need to do more restructuring but get that part working first and then should see new error

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think that's right... the request must be firing because when I `console.log()` for the `superobjects` it is populated with the new response as well as I see it on the Networking tab.

Comment: `jQuery.ajax()` does not accept  a `done` option. It does accept a `success` option or you can chain `jQuery.ajax(...).done(successHandler)`. But, in practice, you should do neither. Instead, chain `jQuery.ajax(...).then(successHandler, [errorHandler])`. The `.then()` method has invaluable extra power not possessed by the success option or the `.done()` method.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 okay but how do I get the request params back in the promise response given how I want to call the Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I used a closure, I believe it does what I want. :)

```
var superobjects = [];
var success_callback = function(result) {
  superobjects.push(result);
};
var requests = [];
console.log(data);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  (function(i, data) {
    requests.push(jQuery.ajax({
      url: wpApiSettings.root + 'superplugin/v1/superdooperendpoint/' + api_key + "/" + data[i].start_date + "/" + data[i].end_date,
      method: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // Set nonce here
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce);
      },
      success: function(result) {
        success_callback({
          start_date: data[i].start_date,
          end_date: data[i].end_date,
          span: data[i].span,
          result: result
        });
      }
    }));
  })(i, data);
};
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(superobjects)
}, 2222);

jQuery.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(function(result) {});
```